# Saving Copra data into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to make a script using Copra. I'm starting with the heartbeat example from their page and I changed it to ticker and now am trying to save the data to a dataframe then eventually a csv. I'm confused on how I would get this data. I wanted to append data then at then end have data turn into a dataframe and then copy to csv. Currently this code runs but doesn't save any data.

I'm assuming the ws variable is what I'm trying to use but I don't know how to get the relevant data out of it and into the data variable on each loop. In addition each loop passes both the name and value, I d like to be able to use the names as a header and then store the data underneath, how can I do that?

```
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from copra.websocket import Channel, Client

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ws = Client(loop, Channel('ticker', 'BTC-USD'))
csv_file = "ticker-test.csv"
data = []

try:
    loop.run_forever()
    data.append(ws)    
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)    
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, encoding='utf-8')    
    loop.run_until_complete(ws.close())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: What does the contents of data look like at the beginning of your keyboard interrupt method?  Try inserting a ```print(data)``` statement before the ```df = pd.DataFrame(data)``` statement.

Comment: thanks for replying, I tried adding a print(data). When I keyboard interrupt it prints a empty []

Comment: That implies your ```data.append(ws)``` is not adding ws to the data list.  I don't know enough about asyncio to help much but I would  first determine if you are loading data in standalone mode before I tried to use asyncio.